# How do I refer to an Excel sheet by name to import Excel data into a Notes app using LotusScript?

Tags: excel, lotusscript, vba

I am trying to look up some data in an excel sheet to populate a field in a Lotus Notes app on demand. I am using an Action button with LotusScript like so:

```
Dim v As String
Dim v2 As String
'Open XL sheet for access to data
Set oExcel = CreateObject ( "Excel.Application" )
v="\\msp2\mi\CSD\Confidential\IT and PPST budget.xlsm"
Msgbox("opening " & v)
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.workbooks.open(v)
Set oWorkSheet= oWorkbook.worksheets (4)
v2=Cstr(oWorkSheet.Cells(1,1).value)
Messagebox(v2)
```

This code does work in that it pulls data from cell A1 - but which sheet?
The sheet containing the data I want is "Sheet4" renamed as "Logic-Detail" but if I use 4 as a parameter as above I get data from the 4th sheet from the left.  I need to be able to cope with sheets being hidden as well. I spent 20 minutes on MSDN's excel object model "help" getting nowhere  :-(
I feel sure it must be dead easy when you know the answer !

Comment: When referring to sheets in Excel-VBA you can do it as `oWorkbook.Worksheets("Logic-Detail")`, but since I am not familiar with LotusScript at all, I am not sure if this is valid syntax for you.

Comment: eirikdaude - thank you!  I was fairly sure I'd tried all permutations guessing the syntax... but not that one obviously as it works!  if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at the correct syntax is frustrating, isn't it? When referring to sheets in Excel-VBA there are several options:

- You can list them by index-number, as you already did in the code-sample in your question
- You can refer to it by its name, in your case this would probably be `oWorkbook.Worksheets("Logic-Detail")`
- You can refer to it by its codename, in your case this would probably be `oWorkbook.Sheet4`. The codename can be changed when you view the properties of the worksheet in the VBA editor.

There may be even more ways to refer to the sheet, but these are the ones which come to mind at the moment. As we know from the question and comments, at least the two first options also work in LotusScript.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works if the target sheet is hidden...   btw is there a good reference work that exlains the XL object model well (with examples)  I find the online help at MSDN to be useless for my needs.... unless I am looking in the wrong place of course.

Comment: I am very fond of Chip Pearson's pages when it comes to explaining concepts in Excel, but I dunno how easy they are to navigate - I just tend to choose them if they turn up in a google-search for what I want to know more about. [This site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx), for instance, says a bit about naming of worksheets. I doubt it is a complete explanation of the object model, but it is good reading anyway :)